# Metabase: any way to identify redundant queries?

Tags: metabase

We are currently using metabase as a basic MI tool.  However we have frequent changes in our underlying data fields as we re-factor/optimise which means existing queries fall over.

Using the metabase API we can identify which queries we need to update through a search on the SQL used to created the query, but its likely there is significant effort being deployed on updating queries that are no longer relevant/have not been accessed in a long time & really should be archived.

Is there any way to identify whether a query that has been written in metabase hasn't been referenced  in a while?

I know a lot of more advanced BI tools have this functionality built in, wondering if there is a hack in metabase I'm missing - rather than having to contact all users in the business to ask specifically to only keep the queries they care about (as wont ever happen/we will delete the wrong ones etc)

Any help gratefully received